# QGIS, Query out some attribute columns temporarily

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I am looking for a work-around to remove some fields (attribute columns) from a layer's table by a query.

For example, there are 10 columns in a table, remove 9 and leave only one (virtually).

Now, if I run 'Join Attribute by Location' tool, I should only get one column attached to the new 'join layer'. This is so that I could get only the desired attribute column in the output 'join layer'.

Once I finish this task, I should be able to display all original columns back as they were in the layer.

I know there is an equivalent in ESRI's ArcGIS, but not sure about QGIS.

Comment: Just to be clear: you want to do a spatial join where only 1 of the 10 join table columns is joined?  Are you using Arc or QGIS?

Answer (score 4):

`join attributes by location` actually offers exactly this functionality: You can choose which attributes to join (leaving the field blank joins all columns)

[image]

Comment: In the English version, this option is called "Fields to add."

Answer (score 2):

You can create a virtual layer with the desired column(s). The layer just points to the original layer, so it can be dismissed when you are done with it.

go to the menu `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` and enter the query

```sql
SELECT myfield, geometry
FROM myLayer
```